# How do I remove 'index.php' from URL in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I remove `index.php` from my [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in CodeIgniter?

I removed `index.php` from my configuration file, and I have run my `rewrite_module` in Apache (2.2.11) and my [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, whenever I click any link, it shows that the URL isn't found. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try this out in your [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file: The comments should help get it tweaked in for you...

This works perfectly for me in several CodeIgniter website installations. Also, if mod_rewrite is not installed, it will send you to a 404 page (or you can change that to suite your purpose).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
</IfModule>
```

Check your virtual hosts file and see if you have these items set -- these may allow your .htaccess file to rewrite the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) correctly:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: thank you shane , i have tried this before from http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/">http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/ but its not working .

Comment: I just extended the answer, please have a look and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks shane , i have set this in my http.conf file its looks like 
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>  but its not working

Comment: From what I can tell this should be working.  My next suggestion would be for you to create a new virtual host, with a very simple structure (not even CodeIgniter probably) and test out some .htaccess rules to make sure it is even working correctly.  If that works then install a fresh CI and get it working there.  Too many variables and moving parts in your system may be making it hard to diagnose the issue..  Simple is always better when debugging.  :)

Answer (score 3):

This 100% works, I've tried it. Add ***only*** the following in your [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem with the rewrite rule suggested in the CodeIgniter user guide. I solved it by removing the slash from in front of index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have defined a [default controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#default). Then make sure that you construct [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in such a way that there is a controller associated with them. For example,

**Home page:**

```
example.com/home/
```

**Or for the *About us* page:**

```
example.com/about/
```

Also double check that you have turned on the mod-rewrite module.

Comment: thanks ahmed , yes i have defined my default controller my home page in route.php $route['default_controller'] = "welcome"; and my config.php $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/codeigniter2/";

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found that Shane's answer helped me out. I have my sites setup in [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP).

```
RewriteBase /mysite/
```

The `mysite` is the alias as set in Apache. This worked for all my sites.

Answer (score 0):

.htacess

```
RewriteEngine on

#Any HTTP request other than those for index.php, 
#assets folder, files   folder and robots.txt
#is treated as a request for your index.php file.

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|files|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

after this go to `application/config/config.php`
and modify these two variables with the values mentioned below.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

For all my Codeigniter projects, I use .htaccess code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I hope this helps.