# Submitting form values to controller

Tags: codeigniter

This should be something really simple but I just can't get it.

I'm learning codeigniter and I have a form with following code

```
<body>
  <form name ="userinput" action="form_reader.php" method="post">
      Name <input type="text" name="username"> <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

I have a controller called `form_reader.php` in my controllers folder. I get a `404 Not Found` error. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Send your values to a function in your controller

```
  <form name ="userinput" action="form_reader/save_userinput" method="post">
```

in your controller, make a function called "save_userinput":

```
<?php
class Form_reader extends CI_Controller {

    public function save_userinput()
    {
      //code goes here
      // for example: getting the post values of the form:
      $form_data = $this->input->post();
      // or just the username:
      $username = $this->input->post("username");

      // then do whatever you want with it :)

    }
}
?>
```

Hope that helps. Make sure to check out the CI documentation, it's **really** good. Any more questions, just ask :)

EDIT: Figured it out. Use this opening form tag instead:

```
<form name ="userinput" action="index.php/form_reader/save_userinput" method="post">
```

I'm used to not having the index.php there, I remove it by using a .htaccess file (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192136/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter) one), so I overlooked that. It works here with that small edit in the action attribute.

Alternatively, you could use the form helper:

Load it in your controller by using `this->load->helper('form')` and then use this instead of the HTML `<form>` tag:    `<? echo form_open('form_reader/save'); ?>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. Is there some setting I should have changed ?

Comment: Can you update your question with your controller and perhaps the full view?

Comment: I copied your code exactly. The view doesn't have anything else other than the html, head, body tags. I'm basically trying to get input from a form and display "Hi $username".

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Do you know why `index.php` is required to be added ?

Comment: CodeIgniter basically uses `index.php` to handle all requests, as far as I know. Check out the link I provided and the .htaccess in the first answer there, it removes it for you so you can have nice URLs. :)

Comment: thanks for this example. it didnt work for me either but i have edited it slightly...I was getting a 404 too. so i have just tried entering the full url to action and it has worked.. eg action="http ://www.example.com/index.php/form_reader/save_userinput"

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the NETTUTS codeigniter tutorials.  You'll have to modify slightly as they are using 1.7.2 but the concepts are the same

Comment: Providing a link here would be a great help!