# how to remove index.php from codeigniter URL

Tags: codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to remove index.php from url in codeigniter ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192136/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter)

I want to remove index.php from the codeigniter url. I have created .htaccess file and placed the following code on it (as found on the CodeIgniter website. But i can not access anything on the localhost. I get the error "Not Found", if i place the code in the .htaccessfile.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My url looks like `localhost/test/project/index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php
```

Comment: This detailed explainer video can be helpful:  https://youtu.be/gG-AP1n7mjU

Answer (score 1):

did you remove index.php like so

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

from the config file in your config folder from application ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried everything in the user guide and had no luck it may be an issue with your local setup. If you are on a Mac there may be an issue with your Apache setup.  I would check `/etc/apache2/[username].conf` and make sure that you have `AllowOverride` set to `All`.