# how to remove index.php in codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

my codeigniter project in mathwork folder
mathwork is folder inside a another folder admin which have codeigniter file
 admin     admin  is folder  have a codeigniter file library all have

```
 mathwork
   --admin
```

when i want to try access as

```
http://localhost/mathwork/admin/authorize/add
```

it show error 404

when i try to access as

```
http://localhost/mathwork/admin/index.php/authorize/add
```

its working fine

how to remove index.php and get url as

```
 http://localhost/mathwork/admin/authorize/add
```

Comment: you need to enable url rewriting in your webserver and configure it through your `web.config` (IIS) or `.htaccess` (apache) or whatever config your webserver uses

Comment: **READ the manual:** [Remove `index.php` from the URL](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove 'index.php' from URL in CodeIgniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192136/how-do-i-remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use wamp and xampp and windows 10

This .htaccess seems to work fine for me

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Place the htaccess out side of application folder

- yourproject
- yourproject > admin <-- application folder
- yourproject > admin > .htaccess
- yourproject > admin > index.php `you may need to change the system ../system`

---

- yourproject
- yourproject > frontend <-- application folder
- yourproject > system
- yourproject > .htaccess
- yourproject > index.php

On config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

You can get more .htaccess [here](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `.htaccess` (if Apache) in the same directory as your `index.php`, open it and add this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Next open `config.php` and change `$config['index_page'] = "index.php"` to `$config['index_page'] = ""`.

Your URLs should now work without `index.php` in the address bar.

Comment: does not work for me i do as you write here but does not work    codeigniter file is in mathwork folder and inside mathwork folder have admin folder in this folder have codeiniter file and i'm using REQUEST_URI